# Why is google ads transfer data changing outside of 30 day attribution window?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api, google-cloud-data-transfer

I have set up a google ads transfer into bigquery with a refresh window set at 30 days. I am aware that conversion-type statistics are continually updated within the lookback window, so I am not concerned about discord between the data pull and the UI for data within the last 30 days; however, there seems to be a difference between the UI and the data transfer for up to 10 days after the 30 day attribution window has ended. (ex. I schedule a backfill for 2020-04-29 on 2020-06-02. When comparing the UI and the bq data, on 2020-06-10, the bq data no longer matches the UI) Note: Backfill data that is older than 40 days, does not seem to have this issue.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Any potential solutions?

This same question has been posted within the GCP slack community.